# Recurrence relation of finite sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve a recurrence relation, which looks roughly like $$a_{(n+1)(k+1)}=f(n,k)a_{n(k+1)}+g(n,k)(a_{nk}-a_{(n-k)k})$$,
where the exact form of $c_{n,k},d{n,k}$ is some fraction of polynomials in $n,k$. Moreover, $n\in[0,k-1]$ and $a_{0k}=\frac{2k(k+2)}{k+1}$.

I have looked up some basic strategies for solving recurrence relations with variable coefficients, using generating functions and all of this seems fine. One can write
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_{nk}x^ny^k
$$
and with the regular methods of dividing by $x,y$ I can create $a_{n(k+1)}$ and $a_{(n+1)(k+1)}$ and with derivatives I can extract factors of $n$ and $k$. However, I am struggling to make sense of the term $a_{(n-k)k}$ in terms of generating functions. I know that the Cauchy product is often used to create such terms, but this only holds for infinite series, which this isn't for $n$. Does anyone know how to go about defining this in terms of a generating function or if there are better methods to try?

Comment: The symbols in "of cn, k, dn,k is some" -- doesn't appear in your formula (in my browser :) )
Have you read Generatingfunctionlogy by Wilf.  He gives a lot of techniques for this type.  If your coefficients, f()&g(), are actually polynomials then the theory in A=B https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html
should be expandable.  I could try to dig/expand it out; but be aware that my mathematical dyslexia has been worse than usual lately.   For particular cases, the implementation in some of the CAS's are pretty good; if checked :)

Comment: As far as a_(n-k),n  goes, I would just move everything else over to the left-hand side and define that as a polynomial product and then flatten the terms out.  I presume that your two definitions of "f()"- f(n,k) - f(x,y) is a mistake.  You don't mean it's the same f() ?  You can erase your sum(n=0,n=k-1) and try to solve with fixed k ; then divide the generating function for x^n, by 1/(1-y) and then find the summation term as the k-th derivative w.r.t. y.  (Probably with a flurry of hieroglyphs along the wall :) ).  BTW: the "snake-oil" method is sometimes productive.